# RFM69HCW Digital IO connection setup

Tags: microcontroller, radio, transceiver, rfm69

I'm working to setup an RFM69HCW transceiver with an ARM microcontroller. I've read over the [datasheet](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Wireless/General/RFM69HCW-V1.1.pdf) for the RFM69HCW and I see that DIO0 is the interrupt signal, so I've broken that one out, but other boards using the same module break out DI1 also which is as far as I can tell, only required for continuous mode. If I only plan to use the radio in packet mode, is it okay not to use this pin? This is my first time setting up a radio myself, so I want to make sure I'm doing it right.

Comment: why don't you run some tests? ... determine what works best for you

Comment: I plan to, just looking for advice from someone who’s done this before